# RSpec testing in Rails and 304 HTTP status code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http, http-response-codes

Using Devise for authentication. On a controller that has:

```
before_filter authenticate_user!, :except => [ :index, :show ]
```

I always get `304 Not Modified` status code instead of `200 OK` on the authenticated actions, even in the browser while signed in. The views render and work just fine.

It's stopping my tests from passing:

```
describe 'GET index' do
  it 'should be successful' do
    get 'index'
    response.should be_success  # Fails due to 304 status code
  end
end
```

I thought it was my controller's fault at first, but besides the `before_filter` and `decent_exposure`, the controller couldn't be any more common.

What could possibly be the root of this issue?

Comment: 304 can only be returned in a response to a [conditional GET request](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-9.3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tests were failing because I was using Devise for authentication with the confirmable module and was not using confirmed users.

After setting the `confirmed_at` attribute in the factory, all tests passed.

Answer (score 2):

`304`s are a good thing.  In this case, it is what is expected (and desired) even though it may be giving some of your tests trouble.  A `304` means that your webserver and client are communicating in a way to allow caching of the webserver's response.

I'm not entirely familiar with Rails, but I'd suspect there is a built in mechanism which is caching your responses.  Here is a Rails article on caching:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

And here is what looks like a way to disable caching on the Controller/Action level (ignore the parts about iframes... also this might not be the best way):
http://arjunghosh.wordpress.com/2008/04/29/how-to-force-the-browser-to-not-cache-in-rails/

Comment: What's confusing is that caching is already disabled in the `test` environment. If I understood it right, any of my controller actions may return this status, correct? Then something else must be wrong...